# Mixing Continued fraction and nested radicals does $D=-\pi+\ln(16)+(7\ln\pi)/2-7/3\arctan(\pi)$?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, conjectures, continued-fractions, nested-radicals, golden-ratio

Let :

$$B=\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}}}}}$$

Let :

$$D=\frac{1}{B+\frac{1}{B+\frac{1}{B+\frac{1}{B+\cdots}}}}$$

Then I conjecture with WA that the limit is :

$$D=-\pi+\ln(16)+(7\ln\pi)/2-7/3\arctan(\pi)$$

Edit : Now after accepted answer there is a motivation the Newman's conjecture related to littlewood polynomials with coefficient $\pm 1$.

Question :

If my conjecture is true how to prove it ? If not does $D$ admits a closed form ? If yes what ?

Comment: Isn't $B$ a positive root of $B^3+B^2-B=0,$ so $B=\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}.$ And likewise we can solve for $D?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I think it should be $B^3+B^2-1=0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See my edits .

Comment: Whoops, yes. But $B$ will be algebraic, and then $D$ will be algebraic. You conjecture doesn't look likely to be algebraic, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the continued fraction converges, then $B=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+B}}$, so $B^3+B^2-1=0$. You can check this cubic has only one positive root. Thus, $B$ must be equal to that positive root, which, by Cardano's formula, is
$$B=\frac{1}{6} \left(-2+\sqrt[3]{4(25-3 \sqrt{69})}+
   \sqrt[3]{4(25+3 \sqrt{69})}\right).$$

Similarly, if the continued fraction converges for $D$, then $D=\frac{1}{B+D}$, so $D^2+BD-1=0$. The positive solution $D$ for this quadratic is $$D=\frac{-B+\sqrt{B^2+4}}{2}.$$
You can check that your conjectured limit is approximately equal to $0.6914204058\color{red}{720947}$. Unfortunately, the value of $D$ is $0.6914204058\color{red}{550671}$, making your conjecture false but quite impressively near to the correct value!

On the other hand, if you want a simplified form for $D$, you should try first to denest the cubic radicals appearing in $B$'s expression. I've tried to find some rationals $u$ and $v$ such that $(u+v\sqrt{69})^3=25-3\sqrt{69}$, but with no success. [Mathematica's function for denesting radicals](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RadicalDenest) also doesn't give a simplified form, although this function doesn't always work.

Comment: Accepted easly one question is there galois theory here ?

Comment: The  cubic root $B$ involves the _plastic constant_.

Comment: @ErikSatie, I don't know how to use Galois theory here. In case you're interested, I have tried to use the trigonometric formulas for cubics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions) and got that $D=\frac{1}{2} \Big(\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{9} \big(1-2 \cos \big(\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\frac{25}{2}\big)\big)^2}-\frac{2}{3} \cos \big(\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\frac{25}{2}\big)\Big)$.